# Middleware execution based on file extension in ExpressJS

Tags: node.js, express

Is there any standard way of mapping a file extension to a particular middleware adapter in Express?

When a request for a file extension ending with `".map"` happens in production, I'd like to return a 404 explicitly, yet in development, the file would be served/allowed (if present).

Further, I've noticed that if a `"map"` file ([the source map file](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/)) isn't present, that the session provider still activates for the request, even when the file isn't present (which is inefficient). So, this would also help prevent unnecessary session loading/saving.

Before installing the middleware for `session`, I've added this code:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    if (req && req.originalUrl) {
        var originalUrl = url.parse(req.originalUrl);
        var testMap = /^.*\.map$/;
        if (testMap.test(originalUrl.pathname)) {
            console.log("[MAP] %s %s", req.method, req.url);
            res.send(404);
            res.end();
            return;
        } else {
            next();
        }            
    }
});
```

While it works:

```
[MAP] GET /javascripts/vendor/jquery.min.map
```

I thought I'd be able to specify the file path (specifically the extension), using the first parameter to `use`? But, I can't seem to get the syntax correct (I tried the regular expression I used in above, but it doesn't seem to work).

#### Edit (the following are the lines above the block from my `app.js` file):

```
// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 4000);
app.set('views', path.join(process.cwd(), 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'dust');
app.engine('dust', dustjs.dust({
    layout: 'main_layout',
    cache: false
}));
           
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(express.cookieParser(cookieSecret));

// I've tried to move this before and after the "map" code, to no effect
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work;

```
app.use('*.map', function (req, res, next) {
  // disable requests ending in .map in production
  if ('production' === app.get('env')) {
    console.log("[MAP] %s %s", req.method, req.url);
    res.send(404);
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
```

Comment: Unless something else is conflicting, this does not work in my app. The code inside never executes (I've just added a `console.log` as the first line). The only middleware that might have anything to do with it would be: `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));`

Comment: Can you share contents of the `app.js` file?

Comment: Edited the question to include those details. There's not much there.

Comment: Add `app.use(app.router)` after `express.static()` line. Then add the map middleware, before you define other routes.

Comment: Even rearranged, it still doesn't work. If I change it to `app.get`, that works.

Comment: My bad `app.use()` does not work that way, it's useful to "mount" a path, not to match a wildcard request url pattern. Read more [here](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.use).